# Find Max Value in a field of a shapefile

Tags: python-3.x, gis, gdal, ogr

I have a shapefile (mich_co.shp) which I try to find the county with max population. My idea is to use max() function it's not possible. Here is my code so far:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os

shapefile = "C:/Users/root/Python/mich_co.shp"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource = driver.Open(shapefile, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

for feature in layer:
    print(feature.GetField("pop"))
layer.ResetReading()
```

The code above however only print all values of "pop" field like this:

```
10635.0
9541.0
112039.0
29234.0
23406.0
15477.0
8683.0
58990.0
106935.0
17465.0
156067.0
43868.0
135099.0
```

I tried:

```
print(max(feature.GetField("pop")))
```

but it returns TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. For this, I've also tried:

```
for feature in range(layer):
```

and it returns TypeError: 'Layer' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Any helps of hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) needs an iterable, such as a list. Try to build a list:

```
pops = [ feature.GetField("pop") for feature in layer ]
print(max(pops))
```